# on opening side drawer window skips to height zero in html css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I made a side drawer using HTML CSS, bootstrap and a little bit of javascript. And I have fixed the navbar as well. But the problem is when trigger side drawer my window skips to height zero. I tried to find a solution but no luck.

These are my codes.

```js
$(".icon-box").click(function() {
    $("#sideToggleBtn").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times");
    $(".sidenav").toggleClass("sidenav-open");
    $(".sidenav").css(
      "width",
      $(".sidenav").hasClass("sidenav-open") ? "450px" : "0px"
    );
  });
```

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: $nav-Color;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}
.sideNav-open{
    width: 450px;

}
.sideNav-close{
    width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top  navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item hide-on-mb icon-box">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link closebtn ">
                            <i id="sideToggleBtn" class="fas fa-bars">Menu</i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="mysidenav" class="sidenav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="brand-wrapper">
                <h1 class="brand-title">
                    HEllo world
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use [`preventDefault`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), or simply `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead of `href="#"`

Comment: also `$(".icon-box")` should be `$(".icon-box a")` as your click triggers the link not the `li`

Comment: i tried first one `javascript:void(0)`. This worked thank you @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".icon-box").click(function() {
    $("#sideToggleBtn").toggleClass("fa-bars fa-times");
    $(".sidenav").toggleClass("sidenav-open");
    $(".sidenav").css(
      "width",
      $(".sidenav").hasClass("sidenav-open") ? "450px" : "0px"
    );
  });
```

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: $nav-Color;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
  .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}
.sideNav-open{
    width: 450px;

}
.sideNav-close{
    width: 0px;
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top  navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item hide-on-mb icon-box">
                        <a href="href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link closebtn ">
                            <i id="sideToggleBtn" class="fas fa-bars">Menu</i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="mysidenav" class="sidenav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="brand-wrapper">
                <h1 class="brand-title">
                    HEllo world
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Do like this ...  :)

It will work for you Thanks...?